# Portable LED staircase light

Tags: photodiode, ldr

I need to make a portable LED staircase light that uses a [BPW34](https://www.vishay.com/docs/81521/bpw34.pdf) photodiode. It should enable the LED driver when incoming light is below an adjustable threshold, and disable the LED driver when incoming light is above an adjustable threshold. The threshold is 60 W/m<sup>2</sup>.

This is the circuit I would like to use, but I do not know what my reference voltage is. How do I know what the output voltage of the photodiode is based on irradiance?

[image]

Comment: Your circuit shows an LDR. Also, if the ambient light becomes low and the LEDs turn on, the ambient light will rise again due to the LEDs and.... do you see the issue of a flickering/oscillating LED?

Comment: An LDR is not a photodiode.

Comment: The so called flicker condition is somewhat manageable. The positive feedback resistor shown on your original schematic (op-amp output to +input) provides hysteresis that changes the reference voltage a bit after the circuit changes states. The idea is to make it a harder for the circuit to switch back after a transition. Even with the hysteresis you would still want to point the detector away from the switched bulb, possibly at a far wall or a window. You could even use a potentiometer for the feedback resistor so the amount of hysteresis is adjustable.

Comment: put a dark cone or funnel over the light sensor (LDR or PD) and point it outward and away from the light & nearby surfaces.

Answer (score 0):

You normally use a photodiode in reverse bias, light causes current to flow. Figure 3 has a graph of current vs irradiance. The irradiance units are different, so  you need to convert. 1000 mW/W and 10000 cm^2/m^2. so 60 W/m^2 = 6 mW/cm^2. This is off the graph, so you need to extrapolate.

I would use a 10k resistor, although your choice of Vcc and opamp may require modification.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fakawB.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image]

And the issue that Andy warned about in the comments is real. The issue is barely manageable with a small night light. With a larger light, it will oscillate.

Comment: Note that the irradiance chart shows current for infrared light (950nm). You would also need to reference the Spectral Sensitivity chart (Fig. 7 in the data sheet) to get a better idea of the actual response to ambient light. It seems that at the mid range of visible light the response is below 50% as compared to the response at 950um. Incandescent bulbs do put out a good amount of IR but the more efficient florescent and especially residential LED bulbs put out very little if any IR light. Pointing a light sensor at a source of sun light would provide a good amount of IR light.

Comment: Thank you, this really helps a lot! I think the oscillations are not such a big issue, I have to design this for a course on PCB design so we are not actually making the circuit. The oscillation issue does make a lot of sense though. Thank you again!